# c# error cs1061 unityengine.particlesystem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have start a new project on unity and i have this script to the particle system but its seems to me to have an error on my code.
I have try to search more for the info but i dint find any solution yet for it.
i have two erros its come on:
1- unityengine.particlesystem does not contain defenition for emission
2- does not contain defenition for enabled
this is my code

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;


namespace UnityStandardAssets.Effects
{
public class ExtinguishableParticleSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float multiplier = 1;

    private ParticleSystem[] m_Systems;


    private void Start()
    {
        m_Systems = GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>();
    }


    public void Extinguish()
    {
        foreach (var system in m_Systems)
        {
            var emission = system.emission;
            emission.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: And what line gives you that error?

Comment: var emission = system.emission;
            emission.enabled = false;

Comment: What Unity version?

Comment: Hi Tank for have replay the version i use is 5.1.1f

Comment: well its come with the standard assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 5.1 (which you state you use) [does not have an emission variable](https://docs.unity3d.com/510/Documentation/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.html) for a ParticleSystem. This has been introduced in later versions. That is the cause of the error you get.

Comment: Tank you for the help

Comment: Yes, Unity keep changing this. They still plan to change the current way emission is accessed because `emission` is a struct but it can modify the `ParticleSystem` class. @MirianStenberg You can accept this answer to close it, if your problem is solved.